# Godaddy linux server session start

Tags: php, session, syntax

I used godadday linux server for hosting. I write only `<?php session_start();?>` on my `index.php`... I also read so many reviews. I tried but there is no solution. I also take support by godaddy supporters. They said that it is coding problem. But I don't use extra code on my page. I don't understand what is going on there.

```
session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cookie - headers already sent by (output started at /home/content/26/11511826/html/test/index.php:1) in /home/content/26/11511826/html/test/index.php on line 1
```

Comment: Sounds like you are outputting some whitespace before opening the PHP Tag.

Do you have a test URL we can view to debug?

Comment: Hi Hazmat, Thanks for your reply. URL : http://www.ausac.in/test/ . There is not any whitespaces before opening the PHP Tag. I just put <?php session_start(); ?> in the http://www.ausacin/test/index.php. Actually my ausac website is working well in my local system. But the problem is occurred at server hosting. I am new to english. So please try to understand.

Comment: Looks as though the file has been saved with BOM, causing an invisible character to start in the file http://people.w3.org/rishida/utils/bomtester/index.php?filename=http%3A%2F%2Fausac.in%2Ftest%2F http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-utf8-bom